# Filtering a REST call with a View

Tags: 2013, rest, filter

I have a list in SharePoint I want to make a REST call to access it. I need to filter this list by an `Alert` Yes/No field.  The field is called `Alert` and I try to filter it on "true" but the results are always completely empty, is there something wrong with my REST call? I was mostly certain I had correct syntax, what else can affect this call and stop it from working?

```
https://mysite.com/site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Posts')/items?$filter=Alert eq true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 https://mysite.com/site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Posts')/items?$filter=Alert eq 1
```

Comment: That did work, thank you very much, I was going off of what I was seeing in my JSON viewer, should have thought about that.

Comment: @user3430723 it happens to everyone. Time to take a break!

Comment: I am now trying to filter on a `choice` field and cannot filter, instead receiving this error. 

`"The field 'Outage' of type 'Calculated' cannot be used in the query filter expression."`

Comment: Please don't cross post. If you ask questions in comments then no one will notice it and get minimal attention.